# 404 error with Umbraco directory urls

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404, iis-7.5, umbraco

I'd like to enabled Umbraco directory urls for an Umbraco project I'm working on. I've set the `umbracoUseDirectoryUrls` config setting to true. Unfortunately I'm now getting 404 errors on all pages without extension (with extension they're still working). Below are the configuration details:

- IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 x64
- Umbraco version 4.0.1
- Application pool is running in .Net 2.0 classic mode
- I've added a wildcart script mapping in IIS to `aspnet_isapi.dll` before the StaticFile handler

The 404 error always originates from the StaticFile handler. I don't understand why it doesn't go through the isapi handler.

Unfortunately I will not be able to upgrade Umbraco, change to integrated mode, or change to .NET 4 at this moment.

Comment: Have you setup the wildcard script mapping in the right location (under system.webServer and not just system.web)?

Comment: The mapping is only in the system.webServer/handlers section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably had something to do with some other configuration setting. After I started with an original Umbraco web.config I was able to switch to integrated mode, which made everything a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

tried "republish entire site" after setting the usedirectoryurls to true ? You can find it when right clicking the content node in the content section